# C# Parallel.ForEach Exceptions with Multiple AmazonS3Client Instances

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, foreach, parallel-processing, aws-sdk

I am converting code from Salesforce to a standalone .NET Core console app, but I'm having issues with the AWSSDK. The code gets images from S3, optimizes them with Kraken.io, and puts them back into S3. Because of the large amount of images and their file sizes, I'm trying to run everything in parallel, using `Parallel.ForEach`.

The AWSSDK AmazonS3Client however does not like being used in a `Parallel.ForEach` block, even though I'm spawning instances of it with `using` blocks. I keep getting this exception (although, in yesterdays attempts it was for "region"):

> 'An item with the same key has already been added. Key: accelerate'

If I run the exact same code in a standard `foreach`, it works perfectly fine. For now I just try to test if an object exists in S3, and curiously enough, if I catch the exceptions coming from `AmazonS3Client`, the first eight always fail, but all subsequent instances and calls work. Why would that happen?

Since this is a .NET Core console app, the AWSSDK package only allows async methods. Not sure if that has anything to do with it. I doubt it.

Any help will be appreciated because I've been trying to make this work for three days now and I'm going out of my mind and I've got people breathing down my neck to make it work.

**UPDATE**

Since code is requested, I will try to put as much of it here without exposing proprietary info.

```
public sealed class Program {
    public static void Main(
        string[] args) {
        using (var task = new XyzTask()) {
            task.Execute();
        }
    }
}

public sealed class XyzTask :
    TaskBase<XyzContext> {
    public XyzTask() :
        base(new XyzContext()) {
    }

    public override void Execute() {
        var photos = Context.XyzPhotos.ToList();

        if (photos.Count == 0) {
            return;
        }

        //  NOTE #1
        Parallel.ForEach(photos, new ParallelOptions {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1
        }, p => {
            using (var job = new XyzJob(p)) {
                job.Execute();
            }
        });
    }
}

public abstract class TaskBase<TContext> :
    IDisposable
    where TContext : DbContext {
    protected TContext Context;

    protected TaskBase(
        TContext context) {
        Context = context;
    }

    public abstract void Execute();

    #region IDisposable
    private bool _disposed;

    protected virtual void Dispose(
        bool disposing) {
        if (_disposed) {
            return;
        }

        if (disposing) {
            if (Context != null) {
                Context.Dispose();
                Context = null;
            }
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        Dispose(true);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**NOTE #1:** When `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is set to `1`, then *all* photos are processed. Anything higher, or not being specified causes *up to* the first 8 photos to *always* fail.

```
public sealed class XyzJob :
    JobBase {
    private AwsS3Client _awsS3;

    private readonly Photo _p;

    public XyzJob(
        Photo p) {
        _p = p;

        _awsS3 = new AwsS3Client();
    }

    public override void Execute() {
        var sourceExists = _awsS3.ExistsAsync("{bucket}", "{key}").Result;

        if (!sourceExists) {
            return;
        }

        var sourceBlob = _awsS3.GetAsync("{bucket}", "{key}").Result;

        if (sourceBlob == null) {
            return;
        }

        var sourceResult = GetOptimizedSource(_p, sourceBlob);

        if (sourceResult == null) {
            return;
        }

        var resizeResult = GetOptimizedResize(_p, sourceResult.FileBlob);

        if (resizeResult == null) {
            return;
        }

        var thumbnailResult = GetOptimizedThumbnail(_p, resizeResult.FileBlob);

        if (thumbnailResult == null) {
            return;
        }

        var sourcePutResult = _awsS3.PutAsync("{bucket}", "{key}", sourceResult.KeyName, sourceResult.FileBlob).Result;

        if (!sourcePutResult) {
            return;
        }

        var resizePutResult = _awsS3.PutAsync("{bucket}", "{key}", resizeResult.KeyName, resizeResult.FileBlob).Result;

        if (!resizePutResult) {
            return;
        }

        var thumnailPutResult = _awsS3.PutAsync("{bucket}", "{key}", thumbnailResult.KeyName, thumbnailResult.FileBlob).Result;

        if (!thumnailPutResult) {
            return;
        }

        _p.ResizedFile = new File {
            Name = resizeResult.KeyName,
            Size = resizeResult.FileSize,
            S3Key = resizeResult.KeyName
        };
        _p.SourceFile.Size = sourceResult.FileSize;
        _p.ThumbnailFile = new File {
            Name = thumbnailResult.KeyName,
            Size = thumbnailResult.FileSize,
            S3Key = thumbnailResult.KeyName
        };
    }
}

public abstract class JobBase :
    IDisposable {
    public abstract void Execute();

    #region IDisposable
    private bool _disposed;

    protected virtual void Dispose(
        bool disposing) {
        if (_disposed) {
            return;
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        Dispose(true);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**NOTE #2:** 1) test for source (in full parallel the first 8 always fail here), 2) get source, 3) optimize source, 4) optimize resize from source, 5) optimize thumbnail from resize, 6) put source, 7) put resize, 8) put thumbnail, 9) when all is done update `p` and exit.

The problem always comes from the `AwsS3Client` instance when it tries to instance the internal `AmazonS3Client`. I'm not going to show the `KrakenClient` because it works as expected and is not the source of the problem.

```
public sealed class AwsS3Client :
    ClientBase<AmazonS3Client> {
    public AwsS3Client() :
        base(new AmazonS3Client(
            new BasicAWSCredentials(
                ServiceCredentials.AwsAccessKey,
                ServiceCredentials.AwsSecretKey
            ),
            new AmazonS3Config {
                RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.Xyz,
                UseAccelerateEndpoint = true
            }
        )) {
    }

    public async Task<bool> ExistsAsync(
        string bucketName,
        string keyName) {
        return await Service.TestObjectExistsAsync(bucketName, keyName);
    }

    public async Task<byte[]> GetAsync(
        string bucketName,
        string keyName) {
        using (var response = await Service.GetObjectAsync(bucketName, keyName))
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
            response.ResponseStream.CopyTo(stream);

            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public async Task<bool> PutAsync(
        string bucketName,
        string keyName,
        string contentDisposition,
        byte[] fileBlob) {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(fileBlob)) {
            var result = await Service.PutObjectAsync(new PutObjectRequest {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Key = keyName,
                InputStream = stream,
                ServerSideEncryptionMethod = ServerSideEncryptionMethod.AES256,
                Headers = {
                    ContentDisposition = $"inline; filename=\"{contentDisposition}\""
                }
            });
        }

        return await Service.TestObjectExistsAsync(bucketName, keyName);
    }
}

public abstract class ClientBase<TService> :
    IDisposable
    where TService : class, IDisposable, new() {
    protected TService Service;

    protected ClientBase(
        TService service) {
        Service = service;
    }

    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool _disposed;

    protected virtual void Dispose(
        bool disposing) {
        if (_disposed) {
            return;
        }

        if (disposing) {
            if (Service != null) {
                Service.Dispose();
                Service = null;
            }
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        Dispose(true);
    }
    #endregion
}

internal static class AmazonS3ClientExtensions {
    //  NOTE #3
    public static async Task<bool> TestObjectExistsAsync(
        this AmazonS3Client client,
        string bucketName,
        string keyName) {
        try {
            await client.GetObjectMetadataAsync(new GetObjectMetadataRequest {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Key = keyName
            });

            return true;
        } catch {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE #3:** This is where the problem usually occurs, I believe. If I remove the `try/catch`, then on the first 8 it will throw the exception with the message quoted at the beginning of this question. I find this curious because I would expect it to throw when the `AmazonS3Client` is first instanced. Instead it's throwing when first used (again, the first 8 times it's called, thereafter works perfectly.)

So, there it all is. Again the exceptions are thrown only on the first 8 calls, after that it works exactly as expected. If I drop the parallelism to 1, all calls work as expected, but then I simply have a synchronous loop which defeats the purpose of the parallel loop.

Also, I have it structured this way for a reason, it being that there will be other tasks and jobs eventually added in, which I will trigger by passing in args from scheduled tasks.

Comment: Could you show the code that adds an item with the key?

Comment: Not really? It's inside of AWSSDK. Best I can do is point you to the constructor I'm calling. Line 126: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/73dd0cbf1ed53ce2ae90c50ae5f88d31205d2f4b/sdk/src/Services/S3/Generated/_bcl45/AmazonS3Client.cs

Comment: You need to show your code. We need to be able to run your code and see the same issue to be able to fix it.

Comment: Code has been added in.

Comment: Are you using `TaskBase.Context` anywhere in the parallel part? Entity Framework (assuming that is what DbContext is from) does not support multiple threads concurrently using a DbContext and could easily be the source of the duplicates, not from the sending to AWS but from your EF source sending you duplicates.

Comment: It's EF Core 2, and I only call into the context once at the beginning of the `Execute` method to get my list of photos that need to be processed. There's no other calls to EF from the parallel chain. Once all the parallel jobs finish, I will be making subsequent calls from `XyzTask` to update the database with the results, but I haven't written that yet.

Comment: Hey @Gup3rSuR4c, did you end up finding an answer for that? I using the aws sdk for .net core and I am getting the error message: " An item with the same key has already been added. Key: accelerate"
I am not trying to do anything in parallel though

Comment: I did, but what the solution was I couldn't tell you after 2.5 years. The current version of the code uses LINQ to Select a `Task` out of the list of photos, and then awaits on `Task.WhenAll()`. I also no longer try to create multiple instances of the AmazonS3Client, and instead have a singleton that is constructor injected. I'd say it was probably me trying to instance multiples that was the root cause vs trying to do it in parallel. Hope that gives you some hints.